# Pyinstaller Kivy Error while compiling: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (...)

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller

Trying to compile with pyinstaller I get this error

256935 WARNING: stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\F\OneDrive - Universidad Católica de Chile\Python Files\BETA APP LRP\Entrega 10 Troublsoothing Library\export-result\8vo Version Full 2023-11-16 Mie, Agrega Docx Epub y PDF\Intento 7 subfolders explicit\build\main\localpycs\pyimod01_archive.pyc.2391526742640'
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\F\OneDrive - Universidad Católica de Chile\Python Files\BETA APP LRP\Entrega 10 Troublsoothing Library\export-result\8vo Version Full 2023-11-16 Mie, Agrega Docx Epub y PDF\Intento 7 subfolders explicit\build\main\localpycs\pyimod01_archive.pyc.2391526742640'

The last time, it was the same error, but with other file into subfolders, and added explicitly that subfolfer and then that erros stoped, but now is with this file the same error

This is the line of code I use

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed (A lot of aditiona files...)
"C:/Users/F/OneDrive - Universidad Católica de Chile/Python Files/BETA APP LRP/Entrega 10 Troublsoothing Library/main.py"

Comment: Typically, you only specify one python file (the top level file that is the starting point of your application) on the command line. Pyinstaller then finds all the needed files by analyzing the imports. Are you sure you need all those files on the command line?